# I need to encrypt MySQL Tables at rest.

Tags: mysql, encryption

I need to encrypt MySQL Tables at rest. I know column level encryption(AES_ENCRYPT/DECRYPT) is the preferred way of encrypting my data but my db table is being populated by pentaho (third party data integration tool)and I don't have the luxury to provide MySQL Decrypt passphrase to pentaho. How can I achieve full data encryption with MySQL community 8.x?

Comment: Do you have $5000? .... a year

Comment: That feature only comes with the paid for versions of MySQL

Comment: No, sadly My organization is using MySQL community and not the enterprise version.

Comment: I dont know `pentaho` but could you write an API for them to use?

Comment: @RiggsFollyPentaho being GPL licensed allows us to only see the source code. again pentaho comes with both community and enterprise edition. Maybe enterprise edition allows that but we are using community edition and it doesn't allow that

Answer (score 1):

Consider upgrading to MySql 8 which already comes with Data-At-Rest Encryption. Alternatively, you can upgrade to MaridaDB 10.4.

You can encrypt any InnoDB table, and once set up it's entirely transparent. All your queries will work exactly the same as before, except the data is encrypted before save and decrypted after retrieval.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-tablespace-encryption.html

Comment: Does the Community Edition come with transparent encryption or do you need to pay $5000.00 for the Enterprise Edition ?  I'm currently running MySQL 8.x in a Docker Container and I might want to implement some encryption for a project at this point.  $5000.00 per server is a bit steep at this point and I was hoping that maybe I could migrate the whole thing to a satisfactory Community Edition server.

Comment: I do not know of any feature in MySql or MariaDB that you *need* to pay for other than Professional Support. (Maybe there is one, but I don't know of it.) So **no,** you don't need to spend $5K per server to get Encryption In Place. You don't have to pay anything if you don't want to, and you still get pretty much everything available.

Comment: Probably correct.  I think Oracle has a MySQL Enterprise version with a license fee of $5000.00 that adds some extra features and support.  I'll have to read up about it using the community edition and see how hard it would be to migrate from a non-encrypted DB to an encrypted one.