# How to encrypt a database at table level?

Tags: database, xampp

So I have been working on a website with xamp server I created a table in phpmyadmin now I want to encrypt that table.how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encrypting database tables in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427001/encrypting-database-tables-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @SIAJSAJIJSAIJSAJA Doubtful, given tag [tag:xampp] and the mention of "phpmyadmin". OP, it would help if you also tagged explicitly with [tag:mariadb] and/or [tag:mysql].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to encrypt MySQL Tables at rest.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593050/i-need-to-encrypt-mysql-tables-at-rest)